# Como fazer o JavaScript retornar um determinado resultado usando o laço for..of e o método join?

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho um determinado exercício em JavaScript que não consigo resolver.

Dado o seguinte *array* de objetos:

```js
var usuarios = [
  {
    nome: "Diego",
    habilidades: ["Javascript", "ReactJS", "Redux"]
  },
  {
    nome: "Gabriel",
    habilidades: ["VueJS", "Ruby on Rails", "Elixir"]
  }
];
```

Escreva uma função que produza o seguinte resultado:

> O Diego possui as habilidades: Javascript, ReactJS, Redux .
> O Gabriel possui as habilidades: VueJS, Ruby on Rails, Elixir.

Ou seja, eu preciso que o `console.log` exiba o que foi mostrado acima, porém é necessário que para percorrer o *array* utilizando o laço de repetição  `for..of` e unir os valores utilizando o `Array.prototype.join`.

Comment: Qual é a dificuldade? Você mesmo já descreveu o que precisa ser feito para solucionar o problema: criar um laço `for` e utilizar o método `join` no array.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Nota: Aqui no SoPT não são bem vindas perguntas do estilo "faz este trabalho de casa por mim", mas perguntas de quem quer aprender são muito bem vindas.</sub>

---

Esquematicamente o que precisas para resolver esse problema é, por passos:

- iterar a array usuarios

Podes usar o `for ... of` para iterar a array e usar `usuario` como nome da variável que cada iteração recebe

- concatenar uma string onde usas as propriedades "habilidades" e "nome" de cada objeto dentro da array

declara uma variável onde o valor atribuído é a junção/concatenação. Podes usar *template strings* ou concatenar à moda antiga: `'String' + variável + 'String'`.

- fazer um `console.log` dessa string

`console.log(minhaString);`

---

3 passos.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var usuarios = [
 {
 nome: "Diego",
 habilidades: ["Javascript", "ReactJS", "Redux"]
 },
 {
 nome: "Gabriel",
 habilidades: ["VueJS", "Ruby on Rails", "Elixir"]
 }
];


for( i of usuarios ) console.log( `O ${ Object.values( i )[0] } possui as habilidades: ${ Object.values( i )[1].join(', ') }.` )

/*
O Diego possui as habilidades: Javascript, ReactJS, Redux.
O Gabriel possui as habilidades: VueJS, Ruby on Rails, Elixir.
*/
```